# Testing Apps not showing in iTunes Apps section

Tags: ios, xcode6

I am new to iOS development. I created Apps under Xcode 6.1 by using my Mac and I can test the Apps by using my connected iphone 5S, however I  discovered that these Xcode-generated testing Apps not showing under iTunes Apps section (though after Sync). Any help would be appreciated, thanks!!

Comment: Xcode 6.1 bulid not accepted. Xcode 5.1 -6 will be accepted.

Comment: Only released apps will show up.  (AppStore apps)

Comment: in build folder it will be shown

Comment: Hi EmilyJ, thanks for your reply. However, just would like to know if only the released apps will show up, how can I test my App (not yet released) which using File Sharing feature (by adding UIFileSharingEnabled flag info.plist), that the App will show up under the "Application supports iTunes file sharing" section in iTunes? Thanks a lot. Any suggestion ?